# Using result of an Excel array function in a calculation

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I am attempting to count instances of a particular value in Excel, from the last instance of a prior value.

Assume a vertical list starting in cell A1: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5

I can use an array function in, say B14 (A14 value: 3), of `{=MAX(ROW($1:14)*(A$1:A14=A14-1))` to give me the row number of the last instance of a "2" (row 10).

I can then have, in C15, a function `=COUNTIF(OFFSET(A14,0,0,B14-ROW(A14),1):A14,A14)`, which will count the instances of 3's since the last 2.

The question is: how do I integrate that array function directly into the final formula, so as not to have to waste a column with the interim calculation?

Edit

The list of numbers represents a level of indentation, so the end result will be a compound of these calculations with different offset checking to provide section numbering: 1; 1.1; 1.1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, etc

I want a single function that can calculate this entire depth level, without having to waste several columns identifying how many rows above the previous indent layer was defined.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a few of your expected results so that it's clear what you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in cell B14 this formula array:

```
{=COUNTIF(OFFSET($A14,0,0,
MAX(ROW($1:14)*($A$1:$A14=$A14-1))
-ROW($A14),1):$A14,$A14)}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. In other words, upgrade the whole thing to be an array function. Should have thought of that myself.